# Change ID on scroll -- weirdness happening

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on changing the ID of an element when the user has scrolled to a certain point on the page:

http://jsfiddle.net/QupNv/6/

The ID is supposed to change depending on where they are.  Here's my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    divOffset = $('#b').offset().top,
    dist = (divOffset - scrollTop);

$('.message').text(dist);

if (dist >= 100 && dist <= 200) {
    $('.switch').attr('id', 'd')
}
else if (dist > 1 && dist < 100) {
    $('.switch').attr('id', 'e')
}
else {
    $('.switch').attr('id', 'c')
}
});
```

It works like a dream when I have one condition, but if I add the if else then it wants to jump back up to the top of the window and not continue scrolling down.  Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/QupNv/5/ -- seems to work fine for me.

Comment: This will cause every element with class `switch` to get an identical ID. Since IDs are supposed to be unique, this will lead to unexpected consequences.

Comment: The goal is to have one element with the class switch to change attributes based on different IDs as the user scrolls.  My thinking is there will only be one ID at a time.

Comment: An ID should be unique and imo static. I'd use a class for something like this.

Comment: I posted the wrong link.  Here's the example of my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/QupNv/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, it's because you don't have a DIV with an id="e" in your code.  That's why it jumps back up to the top.

Comment: Created a DIV with an "e" ID and it still jumps.

Comment: Posted the wrong link.  Here's the example of my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/QupNv/6/